# Reuse animations with multiple models?

Tags: 3d, blender

Is it possible to give multiple humanoid models the same animations without starting from scratch each time?

Comment: I think that's how it works in most games(e.g. Unreal, Quake, etc.), you have different models/skins that have compatible rig. In Blender, I'd recommend having a look at the BVH Motion Capture format. If you have a humanoid character in Blender already, maybe have go using some sample bvh files:http://www.bvhsamples.animazoo.com/ ...Also, spotted this nice little tutorial too: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mLseb477wU

Comment: Also, if you have a naming convention, it should be achievable to write a script that saves the IPO beziers by name to a text file, then when you want to reuse the animations on another model, you would read the values from the text file and apply set IPO curves

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called "Rigging".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The process essentially boils down to first having a skeleton that multiple models are based off of.  You then wrap the mesh around the skeleton and 'weight' each vertex by the bones in the skeleton that influence movement.  You then apply the animation and transformations to the skeleton, not the vertices of the model, and the each of the vertices in the 'skin' move with the skeleton according to the weight given to each bone.

As Tre said, this is called 'Rigging'.